# VB.NET Reconnect after connection dropped down (socket)

Tags: vb.net, sockets, connection

I am coding a socket based application and I'm wondering how I can detect if my connection to the server gets lost, or my server goes down.

I've read a little tutorial about how to do it in python [Python, recreate a socket and automatically reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870614/python-recreate-a-socket-and-automatically-reconnect) but I really don't know how can I carry this to vb.net

Comment: I want that my application reconnects to the server by itself in background.

Comment: you need to add some code outlining what you've currently got and what you've tried.

Comment: You also need to specify the network protocol you're using.