# Test availability of a set of nodes in a single loop approach

Tags: python, algorithm, service, high-availability

I'm writing a service which (among other things) has to monitor the availability of a number of nodes. To check whether the node is alive or not, I'm sending a PING packet to the node every `T` seconds, and if the node doesn't respond with PONG within this time interval `T`, the node is marked as disconnected.

So, I came up with this simple loop (some details are omitted for the sake of brevity):

```
def start(disconnect_cb):
    while True:
        nodes = list(tracked_nodes_dict)
        for node in nodes:
            if node in received_pong:
                send_ping(node)
            else:
                disconnect_cb(node)
            delay = T / len(nodes)
            time.sleep(delay)
```

**The Problem**: The number of nodes can change significantly on every loop iteration, potentially it can change from 1 node to over 5000, or drop down the other way. Although my approach guarantees that every node is processed within `T`, the time between pings for a particular node is not going to be constant. For example, it's easy to show that in case when number of nodes increases rapidly, this time can grow up to `2T`.

Now, I find it perfectly fine, that the time between pings is not constant, but still I want to have some control over the limits of its variation. I'd like to have an algorithm which would allow to hold such fluctuations within predefined boundaries.

Based on the fact that described approach is very simple and intuitive, I assume the problem is a well-known one. Still I can't find any references about it on the Internets. In case I'm wrong and this is not viable solution at all, I'd like learn about best practices.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Check if IRC connection is lost (PING PONG?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853071/python-check-if-irc-connection-is-lost-ping-pong)

Comment: @MoShaikG Thank you for suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. I know how to detect lost connections. The problem is that I can't keep ping interval constrained in my specific approach.

Comment: the approved answer in the post I linked has a snippet which shows how to detect lost connections as defined by a threshold:    if (time.time() - last_ping) > threshold:
        # lost connection

Comment: @MoShaikG Please read my question once again. In a loop I visit each node only once every `T` seconds. The method you suggest won't work here.

Comment: can you include all the code you're using? I don't see any blocking function for receiving the pong, my guess is you would want to specify the timeout parameter to 2T, which would through a catchable timout error if no pong is received.

Comment: That's the thing, there's no such function. Imagine we have like 5K nodes, in this case you'd have to either spawn 5K threads and make them wait on a socket or schedule 5K coroutines on the event loop. Not great solution either way. Instead, whenever we receive PONG packet we just register that event in `received_pong` (can be set or dict or list) and then check if particular node is there (exact mechanism is not important in this case).

Comment: have you found a solution? I don't see why you would need multithreading, if you are handling each node sequentially. All you would do is send a ping to the ith node then have a blocking function(with 2T timeout) to receive the pong.

Comment: @MoShaikG I think I found the solution, but it still requires some time to think it all through. I'll publish the answer as soon as I'm sure that it works. Thank you for your interest :)